# Defining shell environment variables in tcsh

Tags: linux, unix, tcsh, setenv

**Unable to create environment variables using a tcsh script.**

Tried `set`, but works only inside the script.
`setenv` doesn't work outside the script.
`export` says "command not found" in the terminal I'm trying to run.

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/tcsh
#set WV "/p/hdk/cad/custom_waveview/O-2018.09-SP2/bin/wv"
setenv WV "/p/hdk/cad/custom_waveview/O-2018.09-SP2/bin/wv"
echo $WV
env $WV "/p/hdk/cad/custom_waveview/O-2018.09-SP2/bin/wv"
```

I expect the output to be ***/p/hdk/cad/custom_waveview/O-2018.09-SP2/bin/wv***, when i echo the environment variable **WV** on the terminal, but i am getting the error of undefined variable.

[image]

Comment: This is just a `tcsh` script, it's not a `bash` script.

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are set in the current process and inherited by child processes. You can't set environment variables in a parent process.

You have to use the `source` command to execute the script. That makes the current shell process execute the script itself, rather than running it in a child process.

```
source env_vars.tcsh
```

`set` is for setting shell variables, not environment variables. `export` is a `bash` command (and also other shells based on Bourne Shell syntax), not a `tcsh` command.

`env` requires the arguments before the program name to be variable settings in the form `name=value`, e.g.

```
env VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2 /p/hdk/cad/custom_waveview/O-2018.09-SP2/bin/wv
```

It runs the program with those variables added to the environment.

Comment: Absolutely! Works just like expected. This will now make my life a lot easier. Thanks